# Java JaxB Unmarshaller giving org.xml.sax.SAXParseException Premature end of file

Tags: java, jaxb

```
private Course unmarshalCourse(InputStream is) throws CourseServiceException, IOException{
        Course c=null;
        try{
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.sakai.domain" );
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            String theString = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8"); 
            log.debug("---------xml"+theString);
            Object value = u.unmarshal(is);

            c=(Course)value;
            log.debug("---------course"+c);
        }catch(JAXBException e){
            //je.printStackTrace();
            throw new CourseServiceException(e, Error.CONFIG);
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Im getting input stream as a xml.when i try to unmarshal it following error is triggered.please help.

> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;
>   Premature end of file.] com.course.logic.CourseServiceException:
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]

Comment: collect the xml output and check if it'a valid xml?

Comment: @nandal checked its valid

Comment: can you paste the xml output with your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way you use the `InputStream is`.

```
String theString = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8"); 
log.debug("---------xml"+theString);
Object value = u.unmarshal(is);
```

First you consume all of the InputStream by reading it with
`IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8")`. Of course, after that you are at
end of stream. Then you try to continue reading from this stream
by `u.unmarshal(is)`. No surprise, you get an exception with
`Premature end of file` now.

To fix this, do not unmarshal from `InputStream is`.
but unmarshal from `String theString`:

```
String theString = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8"); 
log.debug("---------xml"+theString);
Object value = u.unmarshal(new StringReader(theString));
```